# Shadow over CalendarDatePicker in Dialog

Tags: c#, xaml

There is a shadow over the `CalendarDatePicker` flyout. This "effect" is probably connected to the Dialog which host the control. I attached the `Dialog`'s function. Do you know how to remove it?

Image: https://ibb.co/ZJjqfWs

```
private async void CreateNewDocumentDialog() {
    // Creating dialoge window
    var textBlock1 = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = "Kérem adja meg az alábbi adatokat!",
        FontSize = 16
    };
    var docName = new TextBox
    {
        Name = "docName",
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10),
        PlaceholderText = "Documentum neve"
    };
    var docValidUntil = new CalendarDatePicker
    {
        Header = "Dokumentum érvényessége:",
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(4),
    };
    var contentPanel = new StackPanel();
    contentPanel.Children.Add(textBlock1);
    contentPanel.Children.Add(docName);
    contentPanel.Children.Add(docValidUntil);
    ContentDialog CreateNewDocumentDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Content = contentPanel,
        PrimaryButtonText = "Új bejegyzés létrehozása",
        CloseButtonText = "Mégse",
        // Default button responds to Enter
        DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary
    };

    // Waiting for user input
    ContentDialogResult result = await CreateNewDocumentDialog.ShowAsync();

    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
    {
        // Process user input if Create New button pressed/activated
        if (docName.Text != "")
        {
            var tempDate = docValidUntil.Date;
            DocumentList.Add(new Document(docName.Text,  tempDate.Value.DateTime));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Exit dialog if Cancel button pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check dialog/user control transparency/alpha. If you could give some XAML of dialog, that would help.

Comment: There is no XAML for the Dialog. I created everything in c#. Also I couldn't find anything related to transparency in the class description. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog)

Comment: var docValidUntil = new CalendarDatePicker
    {<...>}; - I believe this adds the calendar. The only option you have now is create new CalendarDatePicker template and see if there's anything in xaml to do with background color changes on trigger. It might be that you will need to manually override some setting or even create style just to get  rid of this grey box.